# How do I bind multiple class names in Ember 1.13?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

With the deprecation of `bind-attr` in favor of handlebar `if` statements for class name binding; how do I bind multiple class names to an element?

The documentation specifies the syntax for a single bound class name but not multiple:

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/binding-element-class-names/

```
<div class={{if isEnabled 'enabled' 'disabled'}}>
    Warning!
</div>
```

Which results in (when `isEnabled=true`):

```
<div class="enabled"}}>
    Warning!
</div>
```

But what if I need to bind other class names to this element? I've tried:

```
<div class={{if isEnabled 'enabled' 'disabled'}}{{if isNew 'new' 'old'}}>
    Warning!
</div>
```

and (with and without the semicolon) ...

```
<div class={{if isEnabled 'enabled' 'disabled'; if isNew 'new' 'old'}}>
    Warning!
</div>
```

The first is last-in wins and the second doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put quotes around the `{{if}}` helper:

```
<div class="{{if isEnabled 'enabled' 'disabled'}} {{if isNew 'new' 'old'}}">
</div>
```

You could also write a helper to do some of the work for you.

For reference, this is mentioned in the [1.11 release blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_bound-attribute-syntax).

Comment: Booyakasha. Much obliged. Acceptance to follow shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Like many things in frameworks you can do this in multiple ways

1) You can have them both inline

```
<div class="{{if isTrue 'red' 'blue'}} {{if isAlsoTrue 'bold' 'underline'}}">
    I have both classes
</div>
```

*Some might argue* that this on the brink of overwhelming your template with logic.  I wouldn't fault you for this way, since it is only two classes, but as you expand your project you may want to consider option 2...

2) You can use use the classNameBindings of a component,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/my-cool-dealy">
    <span>I love JSFiddle</span>
</script>


App.MyCoolDealyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    classNameBindings: ['category', 'priority'],
    category: function() {
        //logic here
        return "blue";
    }.property(),
    priority: function() {
        //logic here
        return "underline";
    }.property()

});
```

[Here is a JSFiddle of both ways](http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/627/)

Comment: Think I need a solution that precludes creating a component for every element I want to bind classnames to. I'm trying to write a helper, but can't figure out a concise way to handle the ternary operation. What I end up with is no better than the examples here: `{{bind-class (if colorSwitch "color-one" "color-two") (if sizeSwitch "size-one" "size-two")}}`

Comment: You could try something like this:

`Ember.Handlebars.helper('myThing', function(value, options) {
  var color = value.colorSwitch ? "color-one" : "color-two";
  var size = value.sizeSwitch ? "size-one" : "size-two";
  return color + " " + size;
});


<div class="my-thing {{myThing myThingModel}}">{{myThingModel.title}}</div>`

Comment: Or this:

`Ember.Handlebars.helper('myThing', function(value, options) {
  var color = value.colorSwitch ? "color-one" : "color-two";
  var size = value.sizeSwitch ? "size-one" : "size-two";
  var title = value.get('title');
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<div class="my-thing' + color + size '">' + title +'</div>')
});


{{myThing myThingModel}}`